# id Attribute of innerHTML value disappears

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I am trying to set the content of a DOM-Element with innerHTML, but it doesn't work as I expect it. The content which I want to set is an a Tag with id and href as attributes, however the id attribute isn't there on the rendered content.

Example Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="html"></div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Angular';
    html = '<a href="/" id="foo">link</a>';
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [bypassSecurityTrustHtml](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) method to tell angular that this html is safe to use.

```
      html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<a href="/" id="foo">link</a>');
      constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
```

**[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzvb7w?file=src/app/app.component.html)**